# Lost Google account information after sync to local Outlook 2003

Tags: contacts, google-account, outlook

Normal newbie disclaimer... I've looked and I can't find an answer, so apologies if a duplicate.

After quite a bit of trial-and-error, I've managed to sync all my contacts on my local Outlook 2003 through my new Samsung Galaxy S4Mini (i9195) using [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/).  There was a lot of swearing as it firstly made them phone contact, but eventually I managed to make them Google contacts.

Before I did this, all my messages and emails were showing my profile picture and Google account details with those messages/emails/etc on both of my Android devices (my phone which is only linked to my Google profile, and my tablet which is linked to both my and my partners profiles).  So, for instance, instead of seeing the letter "T" against the "conversation", I was seeing the profile image.

Under the contacts on my devices there is a "Tom" contact under the "ME" section, and I've attempted to update that with my gmail address, but that doesn't appear to have linked it.  Nor am I seeing my details within the contacts via the website.

I do not have a Google+ account, and I do not want a Google+ account... I have Facebook, and to be honest, I'm on the verge of deleting that.  (I do NOT have Facebook syncing with the phone either).

Gmail through a browser is showing my profile picture, however, that image is NOT appearing if I look at the google account settings... which I'm sure it used to.

Is this just "get people to use Google+" by Google, or am I missing something really easy... or something that is really not obvious in the slightest.

---

Update:

Apologies @dotVezz for not giving you the information you needed upfront.

I have a single Google account, with a gmail.com email address.  When I look at the profile for that (by going into Gmail account through the web, clicking my email address in top right and choosing "Account") I am not seeing the profile image, which I'm sure I used to.

However, in Gmail settings I **am** seeing the profile phote.

I have two devices, a Galaxy S4 Mini (i9195) running 4.2.2 and an old Galaxy Tab 10.1 running 4.0.4.

**What's happening (and is wrong):**

On the S4 Mini, under the "ME" section in Contacts, I'm seeing a single entry called "Tom", which has no details at all... I have added my gmail.com address to this to try and fix this issue.  I do not appear to be able to delete this "contact".

On the Tab 10.1, under the "ME section in Contacts it is asking me to "Set up my profile"... bare in mind this device is used by two people with two accounts.

When viewing my messages or email via the Gmail app, I am not seeing my profile image against the messages I have sent.  In the coloured box to the left of the conversation it would show my profile picture, but now it shows my initial "T".

This is happening on both devices

**What should be happening:**

My profile image should be appearing next to my messages/emails/etc, instead of just my initial.

---

Update

Now I've discovered that it's Home+Power to screen shot (and not VolumeDown+Power as I've read in multiple places) here are screen shots from the Gmail and Messages apps on the phone, with the areas in red boxes that **should** have been linked to my profile, and therefore should (and **were**) showing my profile photo!

[image: Gmail app]  [image: Messages app]

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really clear on what's going on here. it might be helpful to add a summary including 1: The current (incorrect) behavior (for all devices), and 2: The expected (desired) behavior.

Comment: Question updated @dotVezz, hope that is more helpful.  I would screen shot, but the <key>power</key>+<key>volume down</key> doesn't appear to do anything on my phone other than lower the volume

Comment: If your only concern is the profile picture, have you tried setting the picture in your Contacts app?

Comment: It's not just the profile picture, @dotVezz, but the fact it appears to have failed to link the profile full stop. Admittedly I'm not sure what advantages the linking of the profile would provide

Comment: The only thing you mentioned in your summary is the picture. Unfortunately, we still don't have a lot to go by.

Comment: In that case, @dotVezz, forget it.  You've repeatedly told me that you don't have enough information, yet completely fail to tell me what information you need. Yes, I'm a newbie, and I'm aware of how infuriating it is for a newbie to expect answers within minimal input, but unlike SO it's not possible to "show your code" here. Obviously this is not a normal problem, otherwise I guess I would have been inundated with answers... so I will just have to figure it out myself, or live with the fact that my phone/account is "broken" in some way

Comment: Sorry if I frustrated you. I honestly don't mean to be a jerk. This may go against SO rules (and common sense!) but feel free to hook up with me on Facebook (facebook.com/dotvezz). I'll accept a friend invite that looks like it might be you. You can get my phone number and give me a call. We'll probably be able to get things done faster that way =).

Comment: Or alternatively, dotvezz[a certain symbol]gmail.com - if you're leery of facebook. Also, I see you're a UK user. So actually calling me is probably out of the question. Anyway, a call in Hangouts and we might just be able to knock this out really fast.